Write as a subscript above a reaction arrow
I would like to be able to write text with a subscript above an arrow (e.g. k_1) in a chemmacro equation but with this code I just get the text k_1 without the subscript
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[modules={all}]{chemmacros}%le module orbital a été commenté (lignes 3816 à 3824

\begin{document}
\ch{A ->[k_1] B ->[k_2] C}
\end{document}



See also: chemmacros reaction environment align.

You can use \sb instead of the underscore (needs math mode):
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[modules={all}]{chemmacros}%le module orbital a été commenté (lignes 3816 à 3824

\begin{document}
\ch{A ->[$k\sb{1}$] B ->[$k\sb{2}$] C}
\end{document}


